# How can I make several clickable parts of text in TextView

Tags: android, textview

How can I make several clickable parts of text in TextView. Every clickable part must have his own action.

Comment: you can use the Linkify for the default actions like, phone, email, web..

Comment: Try using different textviews. Easy workaround if possible.

Comment: use a spannable string

Comment: better to use https://github.com/ajaysahani/MultiActionTextView

Answer (score 63, accepted):

you can use [android.text.style.ClickableSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html)

```
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Hello World");
    ClickableSpan span1 = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            // do some thing
        }
    };

    ClickableSpan span2 = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            // do another thing
        }
    };

    ss.setSpan(span1, 0, 4, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ss.setSpan(span2, 6, 10, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    textView.setText(ss);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: oh just set a movement methods for traversing between links

Comment: how to change span colour from blue to any other?

Comment: @RishabhSrivastava you can set color in the setSpan method. see the api.

Comment: used like this : sb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#D7011D")), 73, 88, 0);

Comment: @RishabhSrivastava if you change the color how do you add the click listener?

Comment: @portfoliobuilder i used the default blue colour in this.

Comment: @RishabhSrivastava It's probably too late now, but you can set multiple spans to the same text in a SpannableString.

ss.setSpan(new ClickableSpan(), 73, 88, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#D7011D")), 73, 88, 0);

Comment: @RohanTaneja Yes its too late. Only 2 years :D

Answer (score 4):

I store main text and clickable words in different resources.

Strings in resources does not exist for some configurations.

```
    String[] links = new String[3];

    links[0] = cntx.getString(cntx.getResources().getIdentifier("footerLink1", "string", cntx.getPackageName()));
    links[1] = cntx.getString(cntx.getResources().getIdentifier("footerLink2", "string", cntx.getPackageName()));
    links[2] = cntx.getString(cntx.getResources().getIdentifier("footerLink3", "string", cntx.getPackageName()));
    String text = String.format(cntx.getString(cntx.getResources().getIdentifier("footerDisclaimer", "string", cntx.getPackageName())), links[0], links[1], links[2]);
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text);
    setSpanOnLink(ss, links[0], new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            Log.i("Disclaimer Footer", "1 click");
            //TODO run item 
        }
    });
    setSpanOnLink(ss, links[1], new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            Log.i("Disclaimer Footer", "2 click");
            //TODO run item 
        }
    });
    setSpanOnLink(ss, links[2], new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            Log.i("Disclaimer Footer", "3click");
            //TODO run item 
        }
    });

    TextView t1 = new TextView(cntx);
    t1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 8);
    t1.setText(ss);
    t1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

private void setSpanOnLink(SpannableString ss, String link, ClickableSpan cs) {
        String text = ss.toString();
        int start = text.indexOf(link);
        int end = start + link.length();
        ss.setSpan(cs, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is working for me :

in xml :

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_by_continuing_str"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        tools:text="Test msg 1 2, 3"
        android:textColor="@color/translucent_less_white3"
        android:textColorLink="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_privacy_continue" />
```

In strings.xml

```
< string name="by_continuing_str2">< ! [ CDATA[By continuing to use this app, you agree to our <a href="https://go.test.com" style="color:gray"/> Privacy Statement </a> and <a href="https://go.test.com" style="color:gray"/>Services Agreement.]]>< / string>
```

in the activity :

```
TextView tv_by_continuing = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_by_continuing);
tv_by_continuing.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.by_continuing_str2)));
tv_by_continuing.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```