# Android TextView - How to implement setOnClickListener

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener

I need to implement a code of `TextView` `setOnClickListener`.I set the text (How **are** you). In this text, I need only **are** will be clickable not normal text. Please suggest me.
Thanks.

Comment: just look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227276/how-can-i-make-several-clickable-parts-of-text-in-textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it using `ClickableSpan`. Suppose your text is "I agree to the Terms Of Use and Privacy Policy of TT" and you want to make Privacy Policy as clickable, then you can make like this.

```
 Spannable WordToSpan = new SpannableString("I agree to the Terms Of Use and Privacy Policy of TT");        
    WordToSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#32a1fc") ), 31, 46, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    WordToSpan.setSpan(privacyPolicy, 31, 46, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);      ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_terms_condition)).setText(WordToSpan);

 ClickableSpan privacyPolicy = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LegalDisclaimer.this,PrivacyPolicy.class));
            }
            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {// override updateDrawState
                ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
            }
        };
```

In `onClick()` method you can do whatever you want..

Comment: privacyPolicy onClick Not Working. can u give me any suggestion

Comment: Ok Got it. you missed one line  textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

Answer (score 0):

```
String sourceString = "How <b>are</b> you"; 
//mytextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(sourceString));   

 android.text.style.ClickableSpan can solve you problem.

    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(sourceString);
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
        }
    };
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 4, 7, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
    textView.setText(ss);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Thanks. @bimal chawla below are showing underline. i need only same bold text

Comment: @sunil check now. i edited my answer to show "are" or clickable text as bold. You can do this by making custom string like sourceString in code.

Answer (score 0):

```
        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Hi this is @Naveen. I'll meet @Peter in the evening..Would you like to join @Sam??");

    ClickableSpan clickableSpanNaveen = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            //Do Stuff for naveen
        }
    };
    ClickableSpan clickableSpanPeter = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            //Do Stuff for peter
        }
    };
    ClickableSpan clickableSpanSam = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            //Do Stuff for sam
        }
    };

    ss.setSpan(clickableSpanNaveen, 11, 17, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpanPeter, 29, 35, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpanSam, 76, 79, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    TextView contentTextView=(TextView)userHeader.findViewById(R.id.contentTextView);
    contentTextView.setText(ss);
    contentTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```