# How can we display recyclerView in paragraph format

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am having a word file which contain some text I am getting that text in array list base on lines.

```
BufferedReader reader = null;

try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("surah1.txt"), "UTF-8"));
    // do reading, usually loop until end of file reading

    String mLine;

    while ((mLine = reader.readLine())!= null ) {
        surah1.add(mLine);
        //process line
    }

    Log.i("TAG", "onCreateView: " + surah1);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (reader != null){
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I am displaying it using `RecyclerView` it is either displaying in horizontal format or vertical format. But I want display it in paragraph format.

```
listView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));

madapter = new testingAdapter(testing.this,surah1);
listView.setAdapter(madapter);
```

Actually what i want is when ever user click on the line i want to change that hole line color and also if user want to share he can share it. so thats the reason i am changing text file to array list. if any one is having any idea please help me out.

example:
In this image i am displaying that text by web view. but i want to display it base on lines so that when ever i click on line i can change that line color and share it.

[i want it to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqmEl.png)

[but getting this when RecyclerView is in vertical format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKABh.png)

Comment: Why not you use TextView?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to style your recyclerview item layout.
Try removing margin/padding from the item layout.

Comment: but i want that item layout textview to be displayed side by side completely merged as u can see in first image

Comment: I think this can't be achieved by RecyclerView. Try using flow layout so views is flowed side by side like this library: https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Comment: You can achieve it with ClicableSpan too. But I think it will be some complex. Take a look to this answer so you can add ClickableSpan to a single TextView: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34541570/2016500