# TextView - Starting a new line while it's to the right of another textview

Tags: android, textview

[image]

How would I make it so the textview begins a new line starting all the way to the left, but also retaining the property "toTheRightOf" username25?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/model_rv_videoactivity_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="username25:"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/model_rv_videoactivity_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlackFont"
        android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/model_rv_videoactivity_username"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that the twitch app makes use of HTML formatting. Essentially using HTML to style specific parts of your text and injecting the different parts of it into just one text view.

Maybe take a look at this: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int)

You can use HTMl to style the `username25:` part of your string and then concatenate the message part to it all in one text view.

Comment: They have a listener on the username though that makes a screen appear and not one on the message part

Comment: This might be of use, in that case then:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541314/android-setting-onclicklistener-to-a-part-of-text-in-a-textview-issue

Comment: This could also prove useful for you, I think:

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568

Comment: wow didn't even know about this. the more you learn! thanks for sharing